# Simplify $\lim_{n \to +\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{nx}=e^x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I am trying to simplify this limit $\lim_{n \to +\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{nx}=e^x$ into the well-known definition of $e^x$ as:

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{nx}=e^x \iff \lim_{n \to +\infty}\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}=e^x$$

I would prefer a clear explanation on how to transform the first expression into the second one without involving any other exponential limit definitions or logarithmic expressions, just using limits rules and algebra, and binomal expansion if necessary.

Thank you.

Comment: "I want" is really not appreciated!

Comment: @amsmath edited

Comment: What do you exactly mean by _first expression_ and _second expression_?

Comment: @soobster, the first expression is $\lim_{n \to +\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{nx}$, the second one is $\lim_{n \to +\infty}\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}$.

Comment: For real, possibly irrational $x$, the question becomes a little sticky. How do you define $a^x$ when $x$ is not rational? The usual way is to define $e^{x\ln a}$, and so the requirement of not "involving any other exponential limit definitions or logarithmic expressions, just using limits rules and algebra, and binomial expansion if necessary" is not really feasible for irrational $x$.

Comment: @TheoBendit read below. Someone provided us with a variable change for the limit that solve the issue.

Comment: @gatosec They really just found a slick way to bury the issue. As I said, every expression with a real exponent has exponentials and logarithms working behind the scenes. The substitution works by extending the sequence to a continuous function (how do we know we can even do this), then turns it back to a sequence at all new points. It feels circular to me.

Comment: @TheoBendit then if not using limits that converge toward $e$, how do you represent the relations between real exponents ($f(x) = a^x$) and $e^x$ ? Admitting this relation implicitly without showing common proportionality through limits is **circular**.

Comment: @gatosec It's a definition, not a claim. One can show that this definition agrees with previous, more naive definitions (things like $a^n = a \cdot a \cdot \ldots \cdot a$), but ultimately $f(x) = a^x$, as a function of a real variable, simply doesn't exist until we nominate a definition for this value, and it's not possible to prove something is equal to $a^x$ without nailing this down. You don't have to use $a^x := e^{x \ln a}$ as your definition if you don't want to, but you should specify the definition you are using.

Comment: @TheoBendit we usually introduce real exponential functions along the notion of geometric progression, closely tied to $e$. However, when differentiating exponential functions (such as $a^x$), we usually introduce it through limits, and the fundamental aspect of these limits is to show that all real exponential functions are proportional to $e^x$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99760/discussion-between-gatosec-and-theo-bendit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x>0$, substitute $y=nx\implies\frac1n=\frac xy$. Then as $n\to\infty$, we have $y\to\infty$:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{nx}=\lim_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xy\right)^y$$

If $x<0$, substitute $y=-nx\implies\frac1n=-\frac xy$. Then $y\to\infty$:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{nx}=\lim_{y\to-\infty}\left(1-\frac xy\right)^{-y}$$

Now swap out the symbol $y$ for $n$ in the first case and $-n$ in the second.

Comment: What if $x < 0$?

Comment: If $x<0$, $\frac{x}{n}$ would still be less than $1$. @amsmath, what case is of your concerns?

Comment: @soobster Then $y\to -\infty$. But now it's corrected anyways.

Comment: @amsmath we see $x \to \frac{\infty}{\infty}$. So that's why we choose to represent the limit by $y \to \infty$?

Comment: @gatosec We treat $x$ as a constant

Answer (score 2):

Hint: add pharenthesis to the expression, remember that according to power's rule, $a^{mn}=({a^m})^n$

Comment: Huh? Do you care to explain a bit more?

Comment: You know that $a_n\to e$, so $a_n^x\to e^x$.

Comment: @amsmath what do you mean by $a_n$, what is this syntax ?

Comment: Of course, I mean $a_n = (1+\frac 1n)^n$.

Comment: I'm struggling to LaTeX with my phone, but basically adding pharenthesis and using chain's rule to make it into e with power of x

Comment: I thought the question was asking how to transition from $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^{nx}$ to $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^{n}$? Look at the comments of this post.